# Show data in a table using twig

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1, twig-extension

I have a problem, my code is like this :

```
{% for order in aFilteredIgDetails %}
    {% if order.availability == 0 %}
        <tr>
             <td colspan="3" style="background: #FF0000;color:#ffffff">Available</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ order.gift_id }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ order.idm }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ order.email }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="background: #0000ff;color:#ffffff">Unavailable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ order.gift_id }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ order.idm }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ order.email }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

All works fine, the problem is that if I have multiple order.availability == 0 
always for each row I have in the top the `<tr>` with `background : #FF0000;` Can you help me please? Thx in advance. Have anyone an idea? Help me please!!!!!!!

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. What to you want to achieve?
Different background per row?

Comment: I want to show only one the background : #FF0000, even if there are several line with availability == 0, For example now if I have 3 orders with availability == 0, so I get for each `<tr><td colspan="3" style="background: #FF0000;color:#ffffff">Available</td></tr>` but I want to get only one this tr

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to detect if it's the first order with availability 0 :

```
{% set first = true %}
{% for order in aFilteredIgDetails %}
    {% if order.availability == 0 and first == true %}
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="background: #FF0000;color:#ffffff">Available</td>
        </tr>
    {% set first = false %}
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="background: #0000ff;color:#ffffff">Unavailable</td>
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ order.gift_id }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ order.idm }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ order.email }}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

```
{% if aFilteredIgDetails %}
                {% for order in aFilteredIgDetails %}
                    {% if order.availability == 0 %}
                    {% set counter_unavail = ( counter_unavail | default(0) ) + 1 %}
                    {% if counter_unavail == 1 %}
                    <tr>
                         <td colspan="3" style="background: #FF0000;color:#ffffff">Unaivailable</td>
                     </tr>
                    {% endif %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{ order.gift_id }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ order.idm }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ order.email }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% elseif order.availability == 1 %}
                        {% set counter_avail = ( counter_avail | default(0) ) + 1 %}
                        {% if counter_avail == 1 %}
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" style="background: #0000ff;color:#ffffff">Available</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{ order.gift_id }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ order.idm }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ order.email }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                <td colspan="3">---</td>
            {% endif %}
```